# mysql select not working with unicode characters a ä, d ḏ, ŋ

Tags: mysql, select, unicode, utf-8

I'm working with an aboriginal indigenous dictionary. Special characters include ŋ, ä, ḏ, ḻ, ṉ, ṯ

Characters display in a browser but php MySQL select isn't working: a search for ‘a’ finds a and ä, but  ä  finds nothing.
ŋ doesn’t work. Underlined chars same behaviour... d finds both, ḏ nothing.

The specific queries have this code…

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");  //this got it to display the correct characters
mysql_query("set names 'utf8"); // this didn’t seem to do anything tried it after forum searching
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE word LIKE '$some_string' ");
```

All column settings in the database are  varchar() CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
The Database itself is
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL 5.0

I tried inserting COLLATE UTF8_BIN after the query (as suggested by others), but then the search returns nothing and I get an error (mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given)
At my wit's end here, any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the accented letters in the database are in their decomposed form?

Comment: `"SET NAMES 'utf8'"` not `"SET NAMES 'utf8"`

Comment: Sorry, missed your replies, Karol, I need more info? Decomposed form?

Comment: Hex, many thanks :) Search still does not differentiate but now ŋ is recognised and found (and accented chars). But NB database still sees a & ä etc as same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who's looked at this, especially hex494D49 for spotting the typo in my code (so "SET NAMES 'utf8'" worked which fixed part of my problem).
Seems the charset utf8_bin successfully differentiates all characters (including upper-lowercase, but I can live with that).
Cheers all